# How can I exclude search pattern within double quotes in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following line from which I want to replace space with whitespace (tab) but want to keep the spaces within the double quotes as it is. I am on Notepad++.

```
[11/May/2020:10:10:20 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 523 52197 url.com - - TLSv1.2 19922 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36" https://somelinkhere - -
```

Desired output:

```
[11/May/2020:10:10:20   -0400]  "GET / HTTP/1.1"    302 523 52197   url.com -   -   TLSv1.2 19922   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"   https://somelinkhere    -   -
```

Through the following regex I was able to select the string under the double quotes, but it's of no use for me.

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Can you please help me how this can be achieved?

Comment: What is the regex engine?

Comment: I am trying on notepad ++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
("[^"]*")|[ ]
```

Replace with `(?1$1:\t)`.

*Details*:

- `("[^"]*")` - Capturing group 1: a `"`, then zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `[ ]` - matches a space (you may remove `[` and `]` here , they are used to make the space pattern visible in the answer).

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Unfortunlately, this regex is not working for me. I am using Notepad++ version 7.

Comment: @AndrewsDean There is another solution for this.

Comment: Thank you, the new solution you provided is working perfectly. Can you tell me why your previous solution is not accepted on Notepad++? Just intrigued.

Comment: @AndrewsDean If you have some old version, it does not support the `(*SKIP)` PCRE verb.